# Как ограничить зону нажатия на область?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В мобильной игре я использую такой код, для спавна объекта в области нажатия мыши:

```
{
    mousePos.z = 0.0f;
    var go  = Instantiate(popupPrefab, mousePos, Quaternion.identity,popupParent.transform);
    go.GetComponent<Text>().text = "+" + createPerClick;
}
```

Но область нажатия получается по всему размеру экрана, т.е при нажатии на любые кнопки, элементы UI и т.д он выводит информацию поверх всех этих элементов. А мне нужно чтобы метод срабатывал, только когда нажатия происходят в определенной области на экране или на кнопке, которая расположена в центре экрана. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подожди, если это unity то для кнопки можно использовать void OnClick() тогда метод будет срабатывать только при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо. Добавил запуск метода при нажатии на кнопку и заработало.